# Merge wcf app.config with another config file another project?

Tags: wcf

I have a `MyProject.config` file that contains ConnectionStrings, AppSettings, and custom sections.  I don't want to have to duplicate these settings in the wcf app.config file.  Is it possible to merge MyProject.config with app.config or web.config if it is hosted in IIS.  If so, where in the code would I do this and how would it be done?

As an example, in `MyProject.config`, I have a section group called Common and in Common I have AppSettings and ConnectionStrings.  I know I can duplicate this in app.config, but then I would have to maintain it in two places.

MyProject.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <sectionGroup name="common">
            <section name="appSettings" />
            <section name="connectionStrings" />
        </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>

   <common>
       <appSettings>
           <add key="UserName" value="test" />
           <add key="Password" value="test" />
       </appSettings>
       <connectionstrings></connectionstrings>
  </common>
```

app.config for wcf contains ServiceModel configuration, I dont' want to have to put the above in app.config.  I want to read it, does this make sense?

Comment: Is MyProject.config configuration for the application, a library within the application or for multiple applications within the same suite? Is the WCF service acting as the application in this case or is it a library that is loaded by the application?

Comment: MyProject.config is a config file that is under the website.  The wcf library has an app.config file.  The wcf library is loaded by the application.  Basically, I have some settings in MyProject.config that are shared by all projects, so I want to read them from my from my wcf library

Comment: Is the WCF library hosted by multiple applications or just this one? If just this one why not get rid of the library app.config and put everything in the Projects.config (how is this different from web.config btw?)

Comment: That is one option, but how would I read the configuration from Projects.config

Comment: Is projects.config just an XML file of your own design or a .NET configuration file?

Comment: projects.config is just an XML file of my own design.  It contains a configuration section along with configSections and then appSettings for each configSection.

Comment: I want to keep the ServiceModel configuaration in the app.config, but read appSettings and connectionStrings from these specfic configSections from projects.config

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6340473/733289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF will only load the config based settings for a service from the .NET configuration file for an application (web.config for IIS hosted services). Essentially you are fighting the .NET configuration file model.

If you want to keep the files separate then decide what will act as your primary config file and then use the [configSource](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx) model for combining multiple config files

Comment: I actually saw this link, but if the MyProject.config is in the directory c:\websites\xaisoft.com\MyProject.config, how do I point to this in configSource.

Comment: well where is the website itself in terms of virtual directory? It would be very helpful to understand your application layout

Comment: I setup a virtual directory of http:\\xaisoft.com.local

Comment: and are both config files in that directory? Subdirectories?

Comment: No, MyProject.config is under http:\\xaisoft.com.local\MyProject.config and app.config is under the wcf library in c:\wcf\testlibrary

Comment: So how and where is the WCF service hosted? Is it not part of the same website?

Comment: its under the same solution and currently, when I test it, I am just running the wcf test client

Comment: will the website be invoking the service, possibly on another machine?

Comment: The website will not be invoking the service.  The custom config file that library needs to be able to get appsettings and connetionstrings that live under the websites root.

Comment: What will the directory structure look like under your actual deployment will the service be part of the website?